# Report Builder XML no results returned

Tags: xml, ssrs-2008, report-builder2.0

I am attempting to use SSRS to read from an XML file and generate reports based on the contents. To get started learning XML querying, I figured I would use a REALLY simple XML file, so I stripped it down to a single element (while still keeping the general layout of the XML files I'll have to work with). This is what it looks like (NOTE: I have no control over what the XML file will look like. There are tons of them already and it would be impossible to change them all, and I'm not even allowed to if I wanted. :-P)

```
<root sample="N" timestamp="5/17/2013 2:17:27 PM">
  <Test>
     <TestID>1</TestID>
  </Test>
</root>
```

When asked for a data source, I chose "New Data Source", Type: XML and connection string of

```
http://localhost/reportserver/test.xml
```

(I did test this and it's a valid path. Opens the file right up in explorer)

I then began using the following SSRS tutorial: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/109/posts/11173/generating-an-ssrs-report-from-an-xml-datasource.aspx

Based on what I saw there, I figured my query should look like:

```
 <Query>
   <ElementPath>
       root {}/es:Test
   </ElementPath>
 </Query>
```

When I run the query, I get no error but also no rows either >_> It returns nothing.

I feel silly getting stuck at such an early part of the learning experience and even sillier for coming here with the problem, but I can't find an online source to help me sort it out! Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While this answer is a little late, it may help others.

I used this query (below) and your xml file and same connection string to successfully produce a tabular report in SQL 2008 R2 / SSRS / Report Builder 3.0

```
<Query> 
  <ElementPath> 
    root{}/es:Test 
  </ElementPath> 
</Query>
```

The only difference I see between your and my query is the lack of a space in the query line **root{}/es:Test**

Cheers,
Mark